# What are these initial gradients in TF automatic gradient method ?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I went through how TF calculate and update gradients of the loss function w.r.t to it's loss function in 
****tf.train.Optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=None, var_list=None, gate_gradients=1, aggregation_method=None, colocate_gradients_with_ops=False, name=None, grad_loss=None**)**

so I went through the source code in this link I'v found the the main gradient function 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py)
In this code I don't understand why they initialize gradients with one in line 408.